# Touch command kill uWSGI service

Tags: django, uwsgi, freebsd

I'm getting a little issue with `uWSGI` and my `Django` application on production server. I have a `FreeBSD` jail which has only one Django application. When I made code improvements, I do a `touch` on settings file in order to take into account modifications.

However, `touch` kills my uWSGI service each time. So I need to start uWSGI manually else I get a `502 Bad Gateway` issue with my browser.

**Environment:**

- Django version : 1.11.20
- uWSGI version : 2.0.15
- Python version : 3.6.2

**uWSGI.ini file:**

This is my `uwsgi.ini` file :

```
[uwsgi]
pythonpath=/usr/local/www/app/src/web
virtualenv = /usr/local/www/app/venv
module=main.wsgi:application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main.settings.prod
env = no_proxy=*.toto.fr
env = LANG=en_US.UTF-8
master=true
processes=2
vaccum=true
chmod-socket=660
chown-socket=www:www
socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock
socket-timeout = 60
post-buffering = 8192
max-requests = 5000
buffer-size = 32768
offload-threads = 1
uid=www
gid=www
logdate=true
log-maxsize = 20000000
manage-script-name=true
touch-reload = /usr/local/www/app/src/web/main/settings/prod.py
```

**Issue:**

When I make a deployment, once it's done, I do :

```
touch /usr/local/www/app/src/web/main/settings/prod.py
```

Then I have my uWSGI service out.

This is the last log I have :

[image]

Thank you very much !